# How to make markers on lines smaller in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[The documentation on `matplotlib` markers here](http://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html) teaches me I can have several styles of the markers. For example, I may have `'-o'` for circles on the line, `'-*'` for stars on the line and `'-s'` for square on the line.

However, they all appear to be too big for me. Like, when I do

```
axes.errorbar(x, y, yerr=ci, fmt='-o', color='k')
```

I get

[image]

To make them smaller, I tried

```
axes.errorbar(x, y, yerr=ci, fmt='-o', s=1, color='k')
```

but no luck.

**How to make the markers on a line smaller?**

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use `markersize` argument to change the size of the markers:

```
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=err, fmt='-o',  markersize=2, color='k', label = 'size 2')
```

Like so

[image]

Comment: May I also check what the default size of the marker is if not indicated? I wish to set the size w.r.t the current default size.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, still not fully awake at this time of the day.  As for your question, I think the default markersize is 6.  You can check this if you look into your matplotlibrc file, which is located in matplotlib: /site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc.  This file contains the matplotlib default settings, one of which is lines.markersize, which in mine is set to 6.

Comment: Awesome! Clear and clean! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

just so you won't waste time
for scatter plot the keyword for size is `s` and not `markersize`

```
plt.scatter(x, y, s=20, c=colors, alpha=0.5)
```

but you can still use the marker shape if you want

source:
[matplotlib's scatter documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/shapes_and_collections/scatter.html#sphx-glr-gallery-shapes-and-collections-scatter-py)